# How to refer to relative positions in formula (orgmode table)

Tags: org-mode, org-table, formula

Given this table with columns DATE, VALUE and DIFFERENCE (empty):

```
| <2022-03-06 Sun> | 34 |  |
| <2022-03-07 Mon> | 34 |  |
| <2022-03-08 Tue> | 32 |  |
| <2022-03-09 Wed> | 21 |  |
| <2022-03-10 Thu> | 20 |  |
| <2022-03-11 Fri> | 19 |  |
| <2022-03-12 Sat> | 13 |  |
| <2022-03-13 Sun> | 11 |  |
```

I want to compute DIFFERENCE, which is the difference between consecutive dates.

```
| <2022-03-06 Sun> | 34 |     |
| <2022-03-07 Mon> | 34 |   0 | 
| <2022-03-08 Tue> | 32 |  -2 |
| <2022-03-09 Wed> | 21 | -11 |
| <2022-03-10 Thu> | 20 |  -1 |
| <2022-03-11 Fri> | 19 |  -1 |
| <2022-03-12 Sat> | 13 |  -6 |
| <2022-03-13 Sun> | 11 |  -2 |
```

I can't find a compact field formula that would do this.
I have sofar a long formula:

```
@2$3 = vsum(@2$2-@1$2)
@3$3 = vsum(@3$2-@2$2)
@4$3 = vsum(@4$2-@3$2)
@5$3 = vsum(@5$2-@4$2)
@6$3 = vsum(@6$2-@5$2)
@7$3 = vsum(@7$2-@6$2)
@8$3 = vsum(@8$2-@7$2)
```

There must be a way to specify the relative positions of cells to find a universal syntax that tackles this problem so one does not have to compute line by line.

UPDATE: with the help of the commenters, I managed to put together this formula thanks for [this](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/51303/help-with-org-mode-table-formula) post:

```
#+TBLFM:@2$3..@8$3 = @-1$-1 - $-1
```

However, it results in this:

```
| <2022-03-06 Sun> | 34 |  0 | 
| <2022-03-07 Mon> | 34 | 33 | 
| <2022-03-08 Tue> | 32 |  0 | 
| <2022-03-09 Wed> | 21 |  0 | 
| <2022-03-10 Thu> | 20 |  0 | 
| <2022-03-11 Fri> | 19 |  0 | 
| <2022-03-12 Sat> | 13 |  0 | 
| <2022-03-13 Sun> | 11 |  0 | 
#+TBLFM:@2$3..@8$3 = @-1$-1 - $-1
```

`@2$3..@8$3`: range from row 2 until row 8 column 3

`@-1$-1`: previous row and one column left from the current field.

`$-1`: one column left from the current field.

Comment: Did you read the [cell references](https://orgmode.org/manual/References.html#References) section of the Org mode manual?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [help with org-mode table formula](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/51303/help-with-org-mode-table-formula)

Comment: In particular, look for `relative references` in that answer.

Comment: It did help, and I have updated my question with the logic I could follow, but still I am missing something. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, now you can.

Comment: It's basically correct: I think you need a space after the colon, otherwise it is not recognized as a table formula. Also, the subtraction is done in the opposite order of that in your long formula above, so you'll get the opposite signs. And I might use the `@>` and `$>` notations for the last row and the last column and write it as `#+TBLFM:  @2$>..@>$> = $-1 - @-1$-1`.

Comment: Note that a formula could call a Babel block that processes the columns of this table. See `org-sbe`.

Comment: Thanks, @mankoff, I will have a look at that. You mean using org-babel instead?

Comment: @NickD Thanks! It works perfectly with your code. I had a hard time figuring out the syntax. Eg., when not specifying column, it creates one, apparently, for the results, beside the last one? And the references are from there?

Comment: If you write your answer I will accept it.

Comment: I would rather have you study the related question in detail and *see* that it actually answers this question as well. There is an infinite number of questions but if they are similar, I'd rather *not* have an answer for each one. If you think that the related question is helpful, upvote it - if you don't, then write your own answer to this question. In either case, I made my opinion known when I voted to close this question as a duplicate.

Comment: You are right, thanks to that answer I could put it together.